# Cannot enable API on GCP (User role=Owner && Billing account is linked)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using the same process with GCP with several projects, and never had this issue.

## The issue

Not able to enable APIs (Cloud Run etc..)

```
Missing Required Permission
You are missing the required permission: billing.accounts.list
```

## Some info

I am logged in as an `Owner`
The project has a `Billing account` linked

[image]

Comment: Enabling an API [link](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started#enabling_apis) requires you to accept the Terms of Service and billing responsibility for the API. You need permission serviceusage.services.enable on the project and permission servicemanagement.services.bind on the API to enable it. Please follow the doc [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/api-access-overview#roles_that_control_access_to_services)  to check the permission of servicemanagement.services.bind.

Comment: Well, the weird thing is I finally managed to enable APIs using CLI. But none works using the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Console Engineering team is aware of this issue as it has been reported a few days ago. A workaround by the engineering team was to enable them with the gcloud command tool.

A fix for the issue has been rolled out which should take effect at some point today to enable your API's but sometimes it takes some time to see the changes.

But probably you will be able to enable your API tomorrow.